# MySQL: Deleting "orphaned" rows during a table update?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Ok...here is my issue...I'm pulling a few thousand records from a cloud REST query and updating a local table during a CRON and inserting and updating existing records with the pulled data. ie

```
INSERT INTO `property` ($columns_string) 
VALUES ($values_string) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE $update_string
```

pretty standard stuff...but I'm having an issue where records are being "orphaned" if they don't exist any more in the pulled data ie I need to either delete existing records that no longer exist in the new data or update a flag or something to tell my system to no longer process them the same way.

I hope i'm being clear...

EDIT: I should add that the REST pull is actually looping thru several different "types" of data and the INSERT is stuffing them all into one master table, so a simple "delete if not exists.." won't really work..

advTHANKSance,
- mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a column "flag tinyint(1)" in table "property". Before uploading update column value to 0

```
update `property`
set flag = 0
```

In "insert into" clause update this new column

```
INSERT INTO `property` ($columns_string, flag) 
VALUES ($values_string, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE $update_string, flag=1
```

And after uploading remove/update unused field

```
update `property`
set active=0
where flag=0
```

In case if field "active" means 1 - as active, and 0 - is non active

Comment: like this idea. Might be worth including an interim status (2) to indicate that the rows are being refreshed while the CRON job is running. During this period the `active` status of the rows is, essentially, unknown.

Comment: yes...that's a pretty darn slick solution...it beats the direction I was going in using NOT IN subqueries and condition checking.